# Let Support (X) is compact , then X is a complete vector filed

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This question is from my assignment on vector fields and I was unable to solve it.

> Let M be a smooth manifold and X be a vector field on M. Support (X)={$\overline {p\in M : X_p \neq 0}$}. Prove that if support (X) is compact, then X is a complete vector field.

Attempt: I tried by assuming that there exists a sequence {$x_n$} whose limit (say x)doesn't belongs to X.So, a tangent vector $T_x$ can't be assigned to x. But how do I use the fact that support is not compact?

Kindly give some hints!

Comment: It is Theorem $9.16.$ of John Lee's Smooth Manifolds. [See here](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds/xygVcKGPsNwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Theorem+9.16.+Every+compactly+supported+smooth+vector+field+on+a+smooth+mani-+fold+is+complete.&pg=PA216&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: See also this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2585896/591889